# How to create .jar file for already created DB application?

Tags: java, postgresql, jar

I am quite new to Java. I have developed one java application with PostgreSQL. Now I want to create .jar file of that application. I exported the file and created Runnable .jar file. That files runs well but whenever application need to connect to DB, it raises error "connection refused". So can any please help me out and tell how can I integrate my Database schema in my .jar file or alternative by which I can run my .jar file on any system.

Comment: Have you checked your login?

Comment: "connection refused" means the database server to which your application is trying to connect isn't there or the database is not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, your error is probably caused invalid database connection information (probably the url, port, user name and password error and sometime could be firewall in your db server blocking your connection)

and second, on integrate your DB, based from this [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Can_PostgreSQL_be_embedded.3F), seems it's not possible to embed PostgreSQL into your application.
Maybe you could consider MySQL as they provide an embeddable one http://www.mysql.com/oem/

Comment: I think the idea is not to embed PostgreSQL, rather that it does not really run right now, because it does not seem to connect properly.

Comment: Well, yeah that's one problem that he's facing. But, he also ask on how to integrate his DB.

Comment: He ask for the schema, not the DB software... but anyways, still no idea what his problem is. I rather guess the connect strings are incorrect.